# SSIS 2012 como listar arquivos contidos em compartilhamento UNC?

Tags: linux, windows, redes, ssis

Tenho vários arquivos armazenados em um "Hitachi Data Ingestor" (HDI) solução que serve como Servidor de arquivos. Essa solução é gerenciada por sistema linux dentro de uma rede windows corporativa. Consigo listar e ter acesso aos arquivos através de compartilhamentos UNC (\servidor\pasta compartilhada).

Gostaria de saber como posso listar os arquivos e salvá-los em uma tabela no sql 2012, utilizando o SSIS 2012 versão standard, já que a utilização do WMI não funciona com este dispositivo.

Agradeço desde já pela resposta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui encontrar uma solução para o meu problema. Arraste um Scrpit Task da barra de ferramentas do SSIS, dar click duplo, alterar a linguagem para Visual Basic 2010, editar o código do script e colocar a rotina:

```js
Public Sub Main()
        '
        ' Add your code here
        '

        Dim Computador As String = Dts.Variables("vServer").Value.ToString
        Dim FolderPai As String = Dts.Variables("vFolderPai").Value.ToString
        Dim CompartilhamentoUNC As String = "\\" & Computador & FolderPai

        Dim conexaoSQL As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(Dts.Connections("ConexaoSQL").ConnectionString)
        Dim SqlComm As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("sp_InsereTabela", conexaoSQL)
       
        Try
            'Configura o objeto SqlCommand com outros atributos e adiciona os parametros
            SqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            SqlComm.Parameters.Add("@CaminhoArq", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255)
            SqlComm.Parameters.Add("@NomeArquivo", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255)

            SqlCommArqNaoCad.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            SqlCommArqNaoCad.Parameters.Add("@CaminhoArq", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255)
            SqlCommArqNaoCad.Parameters.Add("@NomeArquivo", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255)


            conexaoSQL.ConnectionString = conexaoSQL.ConnectionString & "Password=App_ContratosDigitalizados;"

            Dim Arquivos = From Arquivo In Directory.EnumerateFiles(CompartilhamentoUNC, "*.pdf", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories) _
                           Select Arquivo




            For Each strArq As String In Arquivos

                Try
                    Dim NomeArq As String = strArq.Substring(strArq.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)

                        SqlComm.Parameters("@NomeArquivo").Value = NomeArq
                        SqlComm.Parameters("@CaminhoArq").Value = strArq.Replace(NomeArq, "")

                        If conexaoSQL.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
                            conexaoSQL.Open()
                        End If

                   
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try



            Next
            
            Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success

        Catch ex As Exception
            Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure
        End Try

    End Sub
```